# How to make sure no changes are made to a file

Tags: save

Is there anyway I could make sure a file is locked so that I cant make any changes to it. Is there a command for locking / unlocking a file in vim. Some times i would like a file to be in readonly mode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set the file to read only and not modifiable

```
:set readonly
:set nomodifiable
```

For more help see:

```
:h 'readonly'
:h 'modifiable'
```

Comment: You can also use `vim -R` or `view` to automatically open a file with `readonly` set (see [`:help -R`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#%2dR)).

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is to open the file using the `-R` flag when opening the file to set the `readonly` option.

```
vim -R filename.txt
vi -R filename.txt
```

For Vim, you can use the command `view` when opening a file, which is equivalent to `vim -R`:

```
view filename.txt
```

Note that *the readonly option doesn't prevent a forced write*.  If you use `:w!` the file will be written regardless.  However, as a safety measure for "look don't touch", `-R` can be very helpful in preventing accidental writes.

Another workaround you could use is to open an empty file buffer, and read in the file you want to look at:

```
vim
# Then, from inside vim:
:r filename.txt
```

This is fairly safe since you have an unnamed buffer—you *can't* accidentally overwrite the file you read in (although you could do so deliberately if you typed out the filename again).  However you may not get automatic syntax highlighting this way, depending on your settings.

Comment: On many Unices, the `view` binary is often a hard-link of the `vi` binary, and on those systems, even regular `vi`, when it sees it has been invoked as `view`, will open the file in read-only mode. So it's not vim-only

Comment: @OlivierDulac, perhaps not, but I don't see it specified in POSIX—either [for `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) or [for `vi`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html).  `vi -R` *is* specified.

Comment: Good point. Upvoted.